# Using Synchronizing Timer by threads with Duration

Tags: multithreading, jmeter, jmeter-4.0

When I'm using [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) set by threads (`Number of Simultaneous Users to Group by`)  it works well except when using with Thread group's duration,

When it's used together the test hang, probably because of Synchronizing issue, as documented:

> If timeout in milliseconds is set to 0 and number of threads never reaches "Number of Simultaneous Users to Group by" then Test will pause infinitely. Only a forced stop will stop it. Setting Timeout in milliseconds is an option to consider in this case.

Also Runtime Controller isn't a valid replacement for limiting the duration,

Is there other way to limit test duration, but still use some kind of Synchronization of threads?

Can I add a hook using JSR233 Sampler when test duration over and stop all threads?

I'm thinking of using Precise Throughput Timer, but it seems over complicated for this specific requirement.

**EDIT**

I can make test no hang if I put a value in `Timeout in milliseconds` with value higher than expected in a normal flow, as 10 seconds, `10000`, and then after 10 seconds the test stops, but I'm not sure it fixes the issue completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in stopping test, you should report it with a reproducer.

I think end of test is not detected and it should.

Edit:

You created issue:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62637

It was fixed and will be available in JMeter 5.0